# Karabinerの設定ファイルがうまく動かない

Tags: macos

Macのキーボード割り当ての変更で、Karabinerのxmlファイルで追加したのですが、うまく動きません。

Karabinerのリストにチェックボックスが追加されて、そのチェックボックスはonにしていますが、全く何も起きない状況です。
以下が書いたコードなのですが、何か問題点がありますでしょうか。

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Private:: BackSpace and Return Remap</name>
        <item>
            <name>Left Command to Backspace</name>
            <appendix>Change Left Command to BackSpace</appendix>
            <identifier>private.swap_lcmd_to_delete</identifier>
            <autogen>
                __KeyToKey__
                KeyCode::COMMAND_L, ModifierFlag::NONE,
                KeyCode::DELETE
            </autogen>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Right Command To Return</name>
            <appendix>Change Right Command to Return</appendx>
            <identifier>private.swap_rcmd_to_return</identifier>
            <autogen>
                __KeyToKey__
                KeyCode::COMMAND_R, ModifierFlag::NONE,
                KeyCode::RETURN
            </autogen>
        </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

Comment: In English, you should post to Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow in Japanese! If possible, can you please rewrite the question in Japanese? Or I can migrate your question to superuser.com where they accept questions about softwares in English (I'll need to check with the SU mods first though)

Comment: I'm very sorry for posting wrong location. I rewrite this issue in Japanese. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

```
<appendix>ChangeRightCommandtoReturn</appendx>
```

の部分を

```
<appendix>ChangeRightCommandtoReturn</appendix>
```

と修正し、
**`ModifierFlag::NONE`の記述を削除**したところ、こちらの環境では正常に動きました。

`ModifierFlag::NONE`の使い方は[公式のマニュアル](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.ja)に詳しく書かれています。

---

OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
Karabiner 10.6.0
MacBookAir 2013mid (日本語配列)

Comment: 修正したところ、ちゃんと動きました。ありがとうございます。
また、左右のcommandキー単独で動作させたかったため、最終的に以下のように修正しました。


<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    __KeyOverlaidModifier__
    <!-- from -->
    KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
    <!-- to -->
    KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
    <!-- alone -->
    KeyCode::DELETE,

Comment: なんと(ﾟдﾟ)！無事動いたようでよかったです。^^  解決できた場合、その回答を承認していただけると、本質問が解決済みであることが他のユーザによくわかります。

Answer (score 1):

どうやら`COMMAND_L`や`OPTION_L`といったモディファイアキーは、キーコードとして設定できないようです。

単純にキーを差し替えたいという理由でKarabinerをお使いであれば、同じ開発元から提供されているSeilを利用してみてはいかがでしょうか。

ちなみに、私もKarabinerとSailを利用しており、`COMMAND_L`と`OPTION_L`を差し替えるなどの設定を施しておりますが、そういったキー配置変更の設定はSailで行っており、独自ショートカットなどの実装はKarabinerを利用するといった使い分けをしております。

恐らく、公式的にも単純キー差替設定はSailで行うのが本来の使い方だと思われます。

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.ja

もし、Karabinerのプロファイルを変更することで、一時的に`COMMAND_L`を`DELETE`に変換するなどの切り替えを行いたいのであれば、SailでCommandキーをモディファイア以外のキーに設定した後、Karabinerで２つのプロファイルを作成してみるのも良い解決策かも知れません。